# how to make codeigniter routing to work with paging

Tags: codeigniter, routes, paging

I have the following routes for the news that works like a charm:

```
$word5 = urlencode('mygreek-keyword-here');
$route[$word5] = "news/displayAllNews";
```

and this page display all news with the desired keyword in the address bar. But...there is always a but...I have paging on this page, so when i click on next page link...page works but with old non-friendly seo url, that is:

```
news/displayAllNews/10/10
```

while I would like to have is: mygreek-keyword-here/10/10

code that i have in my controller for the paging is as follow:

```
$config['base_url'] = site_url('/news/displayAllNews/'.$limit.'/');
```

what should i do in routes.php and in my controller to get the desired result?

Regards, John

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could get the string of URI by `$this->uri->uri_string()` method, and set the pagination config as follows:

```
$config['base_url'] = site_url($this->uri->uri_string() .'/'. $limit.'/');
```

Note that the URI library is loaded automatically, it doesn't need to load it manually.

**Update:**
Change the route rule to:

```
$route["$word5(.*)"] = "news/displayAllNews$1";
```

If it doesn't work yet, remove the `.'/'. $limit.'/'` phrase and let the pagination to add the `limit` itself by:

```
$config['per_page']         = 10;   // or $limit, default items per page.
$config['use_page_numbers'] = FALSE;
```

Comment: i get page not found...what should i add in my route file in this case? nothing?

Comment: @user2417624 I've just updated my answer; give it a try please.

Comment: i get 404 page not found again...my url is now my-greek-keyword/10 but i still get the 404 error. should i alter my routes.php file to accomodate this route? check my route file in the question and let me know if i need to add new route there...thanks for trying to help me.

Comment: @user2417624 Did you add this line: `$route["$word5(.*)"] = "news/displayAllNews$1";` into the `routes.php` file?

Comment: hi...after adding the rule in the routee, after few clicks my url looks like this my-greek/keyword/10/10/20/30. if i click on link 2, show same records as is on the first page, on the third page shows 20 results, including the one from the first page.

Comment: @user2417624 Please show your controller/method you are working on.

Comment: hi..i fixed it..thanks a ton. problem was to change the $this->uri->segment(3) in $this->uri->segment(2), since now i have one less segment in the url. thanks for your help